# Issue accessing fields in a Custom Exception

Tags: java, exception

I created a custom exception with user defined fields. I have a catch block where I am trying to access the value in the user defined field but the value is always 0. Not sure what is wrong. Code is below,

```
public class CustomException extends Exception
{
    private int index;

    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomException(String message, int index) {
        super(message);
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Code where I am accessing the user defined field of the custom exception,

```
try {
    // Call another class's method that throws the CustomException
    ExceptionDemoClass demoClass = new ExceptionDemoClass();
    demoClass.demoMethod();
} catch (CustomException ex) {
    System.out.println("Index is " + ex.getIndex());
}

public class ExceptionDemoClass {
    public void demoMethod() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("Issue with code ", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code now prints "Index is 1", so I guess you can delete your question.

Comment: In the original code, the exception is thrown in a different class than it is handled and it is not printing 1.

Comment: Then post a complete minimal example that actually reproduces the problem. The code you posted does not.

Comment: Still working...

Comment: @Turing85 its weird that it works here but not in the original code.

Comment: If you provide a [MRE], I will gladly take a look at it and revise my answer. However, as-is, I cannot see any problem with the current version of the code. Neither from a theoretical point of view, nor from a practical (as my [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/aJTlwS) proofs). But then again, provide a non-functional [MRE], and I will gladly eat my own words.

Comment: @Turing85 Unfortunately, this is the closest I can get to the original code.

Comment: Then this is the closest we can get to helping you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things at work here. We will look at them one-by-one.

In the [first revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59585867/1), there was this line of code:

```
System.out.println("Index is ", + ex.getIndex);
```

The call `ex.getIndex` is missing the parentheses `()`. Also, the comma after `"Index is "` needs to be removed.

In the [third version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59585867/3) the call to `super(id);` within `CustomException`'s constructor would result in a compilation error since such a constructor does not exist within [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html).

All those errors were fixed in the [fifth version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59585867/5). This code, as-is, works fine ([<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/aJTlwS)). It even keep working in the [sixth version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59585867/6) (which is basically the same as the [seventh version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59585867/7), only formatting was changed).